# How to install version control rcs on os-x 10.11

Tags: osx-elcapitan, rcs

I am trying to install RCS on Mac os x 10.11 (El Capitan).
I downloaded the tar file from Gnu, https://www.gnu.org/software/rcs/ but the configure failed.
Can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 0):

You can install RCS from [MacPorts](https://www.macports.org/). First install MacPorts itself and then run the following shell command:

```
sudo port install rcs
```